Does Android 12+ support 8K displays?
Does Android support 8K displays natively? If so, how can I get the resolution programatically?
Currently, I am facing some issues where I am trying to get the resolution of the display using
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

These metrics return a maximum of 4K resolution.
On Android 12, I am able to set the resolution to 8K (Settings -> Display -> HDMI -> 8k60) but using that snippet of code, I am only able to get the resolution of the UI/Desktop.

"Does Android support 8K displays natively?" -- that will depend on the device manufacturer. "On Android 12, I am able to set the resolution to 8K (Settings -> Display -> HDMI -> 8k60)" -- that is not tied to Android 12. That is tied to the device manufacturer. For example, Google Pixel devices do not support HDMI at this time.

A device would need the necessary processing power to support 8k so android cant just make a blanket statement that it supports 8k like that
